# freenect_launch will always stop and flush when I launch rgbdslam

Tags: ros, freenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS hydro on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The problem is, since I'm using freenect to get depth and RGB images for rgbdslam, the freenect node will be okay if I leave it alone without any subscriber. But soon after I started processing the image in the rgbdslam node, the freenect node will stop and fall to a dead loop of:

```
[ INFO] [1419407643.570524704]: Device timed out. Flushing device.
[ INFO] [1419407643.570749230]: Starting a 3s RGB and Depth stream flush.
...
```

I'm using Kinect 1, and ubuntu is running in Parallels Desktop 10 with Mac OS X.
I don't know what has caused this problem, anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200018/freenect_launch-will-always-stop-and-flush-when-i-launch-rgbdslam/) by [wchar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15436/wchar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-12-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Matt_Matt](https://answers.ros.org/users/10931/matt_matt/) on 2015-12-15**:
I have the same problem.
Did you find a solution or a workaround for that?

**Comment by [wchar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15436/wchar/) on 2016-04-28**:
Sorry for the late reply. Please refer to the answer.

**Comment by [milan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27513/milan/) on 2016-07-16**:
Same issue here: MacBook Pro -  virtual machine VMWare, Ubuntu 14.04, ROS indigo - what worked for me ("root cause"): USB settings: changed it to "USB 3.0" compatible and it worked! negative side effect: USB connection to Turtlebot2 broken (kobuki)...fix: connecting the kobuki via ab USB 2.0 hub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those who's interested: solved by switching to openni with drivers installed from https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect

---

Originally posted by [wchar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15436/wchar/) with karma: 61 on 2016-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0